# probability density of a probability density of a probability density ... limiting distribution?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

probability density of a probability density of a probability density ... limiting distribution?
If we start with a truncated $p(x)=N(0,1)$, with, say cutoffs at +/- 5, and compute the density $d_1(p_1)$ of the probability density $p(x)$ ...
$$d_1(p_1)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(p_1-p(x))dx$$
and then iterate that 
$$d_2(p_2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(p_2-d_1(x))dx$$
would all initial distributions $p(x)$ converge to the same recursive metadensity $d_n(p_n)$ in the limit that $n\rightarrow \infty$?